# Is the recommendation chat still alive?

Tags: discussion, chat

For the past couple of months, I have been in the recommendation chat and it literally is dead for the couple hours that the event is live.

Should this still be going around? Is it a bust?

Should we schedule different events to replace it?

Answer (score 1):

The initial enthusiasm (ahem) has waned down, and there hasn't been an actual recommendation chat event in a while. Unless someone speaks up, I'll unschedule it.

We've started a different chat event: [SF topic of the day](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1056/sf-topic-of-the-day). There, the principle is that someone proposes a topic and others reply with examples of works (optionally with a short critique). Some topic examples were [interpretative dance](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1601498#1601498), [guilt trips](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1612859#1612859), [books set in Asia earlier than 1700](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1646622#1646622). A topic remains for a day or two, which gives everyone around the globe a chance at participating. This perpetual event didn't really take on, but then we didn't put the word out. So consider the word being put out. Please visit the [SF topic of the day chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1056/sf-topic-of-the-day) once a day or so!

Comment: I'd still love to have the recommendation chat still around. Maybe people can try to promote it more in their Answers.

Comment: @OghmaOsiris So **propose a time**, and publicize it. Ping any mod to create the event once a time has been decided.

Comment: I like the time it's at.